# How can solve that log

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How can solve that logarithms

$\log _{\frac{4}{x}}\left(x^2-6\right)=2$

It's look diffucult to solve

I was solve but stop with

$x^4−6x^2−16=0$

what is next?

Comment: Your equality means that $(\frac{4}{x})^2=x^2-6$ which is not too difficult to solve.

Comment: $\log_{4/x}(x^2-6) = 2$ means $x^2-6 = (4/x)^2$.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$(\frac{4}{x})^2=(x^2-6)$$
$$16=x^4-6x^2$$
$$x^4-6x^2-16=0$$
then solve it by using the quadratic formula
$$x^2=3\pm\sqrt{9+16}$$
$$x^2=3\pm5$$
$$x^2=8$$
$$x=\pm2\sqrt{2}$$
or
$$x^2=-2$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{2}i$$

Comment: How do you move from $x^4−6x^2−16=0$ to $x^2−6x−16=0$

Comment: @user283144  $(x^2)^2-6(x^2)-16=0$

Comment: @user283144 you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

it is equivalent to $$\frac{\ln(x^2-6)}{\ln(\frac{4}{x})}=2$$ and further we get
$$\ln(x^2-6)=\ln((\frac{4}{x})^2)$$ and this is equivalent to
$$x^4-6x^2-16=0$$ Now set $x^2=t$ and solve the quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: raise $4/x$ to both sides

\begin{align}
\log_{\frac{4}{x}}\left(x^2-6\right)&=2\\
\left(\frac4x\right)^{\left(\log_{\frac{4}{x}}\left(x^2-6\right)\right)}&=\left(\frac4x\right)^2\\
\end{align}

Comment: I was solve but stop with

$x^4-6x^2-16=0$

Comment: Substitute $u=x^2$ and get $u^2-6u-16=0$, solve for $u$ and get $u=\text{something}$ and plug back $x$ to get $x^2=\text{something}$, this is essentially what E.H.E did in his answer.